# Build failure when running “mvn clean” for the first time while installing

Tags: maven

I'm new to Maven and trying to use this for the first time in my project.

I've set the system variables;

JAVA_HOME System Variable
M2_HOME System Variable
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin; to System Path

In cmd prompt using "mvn -version" i can see all relevant details.

But when I run "mvn clean”, I get the following error

```
C:\Users\Naina Mantry>mvn clean

[INFO] Scanning for projects...

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Total time: 0.105 s

[INFO] Finished at: 2016-02-15T08:00:48+05:30

[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/86M

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\Users\Naina
 Mantry). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]

[ERROR]

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR]

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] 
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

I'm not able to understand, how to fix it. kindly help me please...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you have `pom.xml` inside `C:\Users\Naina Mantry`?

Answer (score 0):

when you run Maven, you need to run it from your proyect directory, where you have your workspace. You need to have a pom.xml file on that Directory.

For example:

```
C:\Users\Naina Mantry\workspace\proyect
```

and on that directory you run mvn clean

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be executing mvn clean from a wrong directory. Make sure there is a relevant pom.xml. Maven by default refers to the current working directory. Alternately, you can use -f option to specify a pom.xml located in a different directory.